# How to get "short circuit" in sql query?

Tags: sql

I am meeting a database query demand like this:

1. If there is a record in which the column of 'type' is '1', then return the record.

```sql
select * from table where type = 1;
# if the result is not empty, then return it
```

Otherwise,

2. return the record  in which the 'type' is '2'

```sql
select * from table where type = 2;
# even the result is empty
```

So, how can I merge the two queries into only one, like short circuit:

```sql
select * from table where type = 1 (short-circuit-or) type = 2;
# when 'type = 1' matches records, it will not execute 'type = 2'; otherwise, it does like 'union' action.
```

---

I will explain why I ask such question. Indeed, the first 3 answers are correct but not 'good' enough. I expect the time consumption is good as query of 'type = 1'. But `union` and `in (1, 2)` will cause the DBMS to query `type = 2`, which will slow the speed even `type = 1` matches record.

Comment: Please provide DDL + DML commands, sample data and expected output. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please pick up only one of those tagged DBMS which are differrent ?

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle you can try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE type IN (1, 2)
ORDER BY type
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

In MySQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE type IN (1, 2)
ORDER BY type
LIMIT 1;
```

The idea is to get the rows, order them by some criteria and get the first one only.

Comment: So it still query type 2 even type 1 matches?

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server "the best" query plan for query

```
select top 1 with ties *
from test where type>=1
order by type;
```

if exists clustered index on `type`
[example here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Bmt_rheA)